# Rails Webpage won't Play any Audio or Show Audio Controls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, audio, web, asset-pipeline

I'm developing a ruby on rails application, and would simply like there to be a button on one of my tables' show.html.erb pages that plays a single audio file. The html.erb file below will do all of this flawlessly when it's opened manually in firefox, but not when it gets called by my rails server. Instead there is no autoplay, and the button shows up but does nothing when you click it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
</head>

<button onclick="playAud()" type="button">Play</button>

<audio id = "audio" autoplay>
    <source src= 'my audio.mp3' type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script> 
var audio = document.getElementById("audio"); 
   function playAud() { 
        audio.play(); 
    } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, when I add the controls command to the html audio tag, I sometimes see the controls flash briefly on the screen then disappear.

In my final html.erb I will be using a lot of controller-created variables and such, but right now I'm just trying to get this simple issue resolved. My controller's show method is all commented out at the moment.

How can I get this audio button to work?

When I go to the rails server on the console, I see this at the end of the list of actions performed:

> Started GET "/phrases/my%20audio.mp3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-24
>   17:29:21 -0600 Processing by PhrasesController#show as 
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"my audio"}   Rendered phrases/show.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (0.9ms)

So it looks like the server is recognizing 'my audio.mp3' as a parameter it needs to "GET" for some reason... no idea why it would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I haven't been using the *only* default asset folder (still don't know how to add more, but I'll figure it out eventually), which is (duh) the "public" folder. When I placed my audio in the public folder and changed the source of the audio to '/my audio.mp3', it worked!

```
<audio autoplay>
 <source src='/my audio.mp3' type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I'm so glad that's over... so painful!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you put your media file into same dir as your html then update code to find it as

```
    <source src= 'your_audio.mp3' type="audio/mpeg">
```

Avoid full path to a location outside visability of a web server (security restrictions prevent web server from seeing files in arbitrary locations) ... once working identify more appropriate media dir as defined by web server config

Comment: Just did this and it didn't work :-(. To ensure the code was written correctly, I ran it raw in firefox and it worked fine. Do you think that the web server config thing might help?

Comment: It looks like my application is picking up the html: src = 'my audio.mp3' as if it's a parameter. Why on earth would it try to treat this as a parameter? This is insanely frustrating...